# How to Pass A variable in json to get data

Tags: reactjs

I have to Get data from a json file with help of an input field data
. Please Consider this symbol as my problem : ~

```
const inputdata = document.getElementById('myinput').value
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then((value) => value.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json.~)
    });
```

In the place of this ~ symbol i have to place my variable inputdata . how i can do that please help me

Comment: Do you mean the value of `myinput` is json?

Comment: If possible, kindly explain in little detail

Comment: Yes the value of myinput in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need, though, if you asking about dynamically accessing an object's keys, here's the solution:
You have to use square brackets, as in the example below.

```
const json = {a: 1, b: 2}
const inputData = "a";

console.log(json[inputData]); // 1
```

Hope it helps. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

[Refer this link for more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code, you could do `console.log(json[inputdata])`